# How to fix google login error 16 with cordova-plugin-googleplus?

Tags: ionic3

I am using `cordova-plugin-googleplus` in my Ionic 3 app. It was previously worked fine, but now it is returning "**google login error 16**"

Any idea what is causing this or how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: try https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/529#issuecomment-421319226

Comment: please give step to google plus login

Answer (score 0):

This is always a problem because the signature (or fingerprint) of your app when signed is not added to the google console (or firebase) Oauth whitelist.

Make sure you fully read and understand the [guide on App Signing from the android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

After reading that the steps you need to take:

#### 1. Make a keystore

Make a local keystore and key with the android studio or via terminal (this can be used as official app signing key, or just as upload key, either is fine)

In the case you only have one official key and do not enroll *Google Play App Signing* then go to 3A. If you do enroll in *Google Play App Signing* your local key will be your *upload key*. In this case go to 3B.

#### 2A. Without *Google Play App Signing*

You only have 1 local key which is your official app signing key.

You need to whitelist the following key fingerprints (in SHA1 format) in Google Oauth settings:

- android default `debug.keystore` key
- your own created keystore with its key (for App Signing)

#### 2B. With *Google Play App Signing* enabled

You have local "upload key" and one official "App Signing key" which is stored only on Google servers

You need to whitelist the following key fingerprints (in SHA1 format) in Google Oauth settings:

- android default `debug.keystore` key
- your own created keystore with its key (for Uploading)
- google's App Signing key

#### 3. Get key fingerprints

Get the above keys' fingerprints (in SHA1 format) to be able to whitelist them.

#### A. Debug key

For the android default `debug.keystore` do:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore /Users/myusername/.android/debug.keystore  -list -v
```

You will see the SHA1 fingerprint for the debug key in terminal. Copy that.

#### B. App signing or Upload key

For the own created keystore with key (either for 3A or 3B) do:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore /path/to/your/key/yourKeystoreFile.keystore  -list -v
```

You will see the SHA1 fingerprint for the debug key in terminal. Copy that.

#### C. Google's App signing key

Only when *Google Play App Signing* is enabled (3B). You can find the key Google will use to sign your builds in the Google Play Console.

*Requirement:* You need to have finished the basic info on your android app and then you need to upload a signed APK for internal testing. Once this is uploaded you will be able to access the following menu:

Go to Release Management > App sigining. There you will see

- "App signing certificate" and SHA-1 fingerprint
- "Upload certificate" and SHA-1 fingerprint

The "Upload" one is (and should be) the same as key B. above. And the "App signing certificate" is the key that Google will use. Copy this one.

#### 4. Whitelist the key fingerprints

Again we have 2 options to whitelist them. Projects that use only the *Google Cloud Platform* or projects that use *Firebase*.

#### A. Google Cloud Platform projects

(In case you also use Firebase, you can skip this step)

1. Go to [API & Services > credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
2. Create credentials > OAuth client ID
3. choose "android" and insert your SHA1
4. Repeat this for all keys (2 or 3)

#### B. Firebase projects

1. Go to the console > Projects settings
2. Select your Android app at the bottom. (if you don't have any, add an android app, you can ignore the whole tutorial they give you, it's irrelevant for Cordova apps)
3. Add the finger prints to the "SHA certificate fingerprints" section.
4. Double check your Google Cloud console: [API & Services > credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and see that Firebase has added these automatically at the bottom under "OAuth 2.0 client IDs"